# Define a constant object in python

Tags: python, oop

I defined a class Factor in the file factor.py:

```
class Factor:
    def __init__(self, var, value):
        self.var = var          # hold variable names
        self.value = value  # hold probability values
```

For convenience and code cleanliness, I want to define a constant variable and be able to access it as Factor.empty

```
 empty = Factor([], None)
```

What is the common way to do this? Should I put in the class definition, or outside? I'm thinking of putting it outside the class definition, but then I wouln't be able to refer to it as Factor.empty then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it outside the class definition, just do this:

```
class Factor:
    ...

Factor.empty = Factor([], None)
```

But bear in mind, this isn't a "constant".  You could easily do something to change the value of `empty` or its attributes. For example:

```
Factor.empty = something_else
```

Or:

```
Factor.empty.var.append("a value")
```

So if you pass `Factor.empty` to any code that manipulates it, you might find it less empty than you wanted.

---

One solution to that problem is to re-create a *new* empty `Factor` each time someone accesses `Factor.empty`:

```
class FactorType(type):
    @property
    def empty(cls):
        return Factor([], None)

class Factor(object):
    __metaclass__ = FactorType
    ...
```

This adds an `empty` property to the `Factor` class. You are safe to do what you want with it, as every time you access `empty`, a new empty `Factor` is created.